# Variables from mySQL within css not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use a form to set colors in a table in my database, then call those colors into my stylesheet (style.php)

Defining the color variables manually works:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css"); 
    $color1  = '#cc0000';
?>

#thisdiv { background-color: <?php echo $color1; ?>; }
```

But this does not:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css"); 
    $getSettings = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE setting_id = 1");
    $setting     = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSettings);
    $color1      = $setting['setting_color1'];
?>

#thisdiv { background-color: <?php echo $color1; ?>; }
```

My 'settings' table looks like this:

```
setting_id | setting_color1 | setting_color2 | setting_color3
1          | #cc0000        | #000000        | #ffffff
```

How can I get this working properly? Maybe I am doing something wrong, or maybe I am just overlooking something stupid. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try inspecting the code and verify what is in there. You can do this by pressing CTRL+U

Comment: How this code is supposed to work without a database connection?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes there is nothing in `background-color` - it's just empty.
@YourCommonSense $db connection is defined elsewhere. It was tested and is working properly. I figured that would be assumed, sorry. The query was checked (as per a comment below) and is working also.

Comment: Run a `var_dump($setting)` before you echo it and check the values.

Comment: A db connection doesn't work if you define it elsewhere and have not a single reference to it in your code

Comment: Is everything working? No update, no reply..

Comment: Yes - I'm not sure why but by simply making it a prepared statement it began to work properly. Since then, however, I've went in an entirely different direction and no longer have the finished code to share. So for that, I apologize. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css"); 
    $getSettings = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE setting_id = 1");
    // --------------------------^ and where is that defined?
    $setting     = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSettings);
    $color1      = $setting['setting_color1'];
?>

#thisdiv { background-color: <?php echo $color1; ?>; }
```

You should always verify if your query ran successfully, isn't that hard.

```
<?php
  if($result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM table') != false){
    var_dump(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
    // hurray, query ran successfully.
    // Now execute the code that sets the variable.
  } else {
    // On fail, perhaps load from cache?
  }
?>
```

Secondly, your DB structure is wrong in my opinion. Try something like the following.

settings:

```
id (primary key)| key (varchar)| value (varchar)| type (varchar)| decryption (text) | theme (int)
1                 mycolor        AABBCC           hex             Background of we..   1

$sql = 'SELECT key, value, type FROM settings WHERE theme = 1'; // etc..
```

This way, you have much more control over your 'theme'. Then you can while-fetch the results and set: `$arr[$row['key']] = $row['value']`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have $db defined elsewhere, but the connection was tested and is working properly. I checked my query with your code above and it was successful as well.

Comment: If that's the case, try the updated code it would show debug output that is actually quite important to know.